# Data differences between Apple Contacts and GMail Contacts?

Tags: contacts, gmail

I'm thinking of [syncing my Mac's contacts with Google](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11563). But I'm a little wary of any data syncing between platforms, since some data is usually lost.

Is there a list somewhere that describes which fields might get lost or changed during this synchronization?